# What is the meaning of "holiday in Katmandu"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read the good article about data science.

[Practical advice for analysis of large, complex data sets](https://www.unofficialgoogledatascience.com/2016/10/practical-advice-for-analysis-of-large.html)

But, in section of "Make hypotheses and look for evidence", suddenly a strange phrase appeared.

> If you believe an anomaly is due to the launch of some other feature or a holiday in **Katmandu**, make sure that the population the feature launched to is the only one affected by the anomaly.

huh? I got no ideas about why Katmandu, the city of Nepal, is appeared in that text.

Is it just example of anomaly event? or is there any other meaning or idiom?

Comment: It's very possible that this is a typo and the author meant to say "the launch of some other feature **for** a holiday in Katmandu..." - this is the only way I can make sense of it and the sentence that follows.  It's not an idiom.

Comment: Is just an example of something that could produce an anomaly. Instead, just put the Antartica or any weird place you would label as

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is writing about data collected about the number of searches. One question that arises is "what is causing this change in search rates from a particular part of the world, or for a particular term?"

The choice of "Katmandu" is rhetorical, an example of a strange, distant cause. The author chooses this as a deliberate exaggeration. From the perspective of the American reader, Kathmandu is remote, and so "a holiday in Katmandu" would not normally be expected to explain some feature of American search data. Though it may have a big effect on searches coming from Nepal.

This example is chosen, in part, because it seems weird - that makes his example more memorable. It's not a common example, or a fixed phrase or idiom. (The usual example of a remote city is Timbuktu.)

He is saying, if you propose some weird explanation for a feature in your data, make sure that it is supported by evidence. A festival in Kathmandu could conceivably affect searches coming from Nepal, or for items specifically associated with that festival. It wouldn't be a strong hypothesis to explain changes in the number of searches coming from the USA on an unrelated topic.

Comment: "If you believe an anomaly is due to the launch of some other feature or a holiday in Katmandu, make sure that the population the feature launched to is the only one affected by the anomaly."

Comment: "the population the feature launched to" here is clearly "Katmandu".  (If not, find me the referent!)   This completely contradicts your premise - that Katmandu is completely unrelated to the potential cause of the error.   And - I am somewhat certain these authors in particular would not use such exclusionary, insensitive language as you imply they have.   Rather - I think there is a typographical error present, as I indicate above.   I will go ahead and ask them to clarify.

Comment: I suppose that is possible.  My understanding is that the article is about websearch data, and so it is conceivable that a holiday in Kathmandu could affect the rate of search for some things related to that holiday.  So "or" would be possible.  On the other hand I've just noticed the author hasn't spelled "Kathmandu" in the standard way, so I don't think there is much thought gone into this example.

Comment: I've fill out some more of my reasoning, but this is rapidly moving away from being an ELL answer.

Comment: "The choice of "Katmandu" is rhetorical, an example of a strange, distant cause."  Funny, it doesn't seem strange and distant to Nepali / Nepami data scientists living there who are reading this article?

Comment: Read the words.  "From the perspective of an American reader".  Sorry but if you aren't used to the America being so important, [they cut Asia in half](https://external-preview.redd.it/0YGOG3jqNGTMlARbWMJARtbGRsyvB8xx5PBw307ahgg.jpg?auto=webp&s=4680fcd5e91e60efed46eef46500a36db7ccd8da) Then get used to it!  And of course far far more readers of this blog *written in English* will be American than Nepali.

Comment: @BadZen I found two examples of rhetorical usage [“The song clearly was meant to be a "bop of the summer" contender with every gay bar **from here to Kathmandu** putting it in the rotation every hour on the hour.”](https://www.out.com/music/2020/5/22/watch-lady-gaga-and-ariana-grandes-rain-me-music-video) and [“Then came the day when they cut the electricity and the water at the same time, …. I had 3 months with dishes and rotten rests of food **from here to Katmandu**, no fridge working, no clean clothes,…”](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-doesnt-kill-you-eatraxx-music4motion-)

Answer (score 1):

It refers to a **public holiday** which may change peoples behaviour.

A data scientist may see features in their data that they can't explain -- perhaps more or fewer people using their web site on a particular day

They'll want to explain it, and they might realise that the day in question was a public holiday in Nepal, that is *a holiday in Kathmandu*. That could mean that people were more likely to use their web site, because they weren't at work, or less likely because they were out doing other activities.

Before jumping to conclusions and accepting this explanation, it's important to check for corroborating evidence: were the missing/extra users from Nepal? Does the anomaly fit with the Nepalese timezone? And any other evidence you can get.

Comment: You've just cut and pasted the text of the article.   Can you add some exposition, perhaps?

Comment: It's paraphrased, not cut and pasted.

Answer (score -1):

I believe 'Holiday in Katmandu' were used in the 50-60s as a common way to say something rare, specifically once in a lifetime. It has since gone out of use (it wasn't that wide spread to begin with either)

I haven't been able to find any reference to this claim, so I might be remembering wrong. But it does seem to fit in the sentence.

Comment: Why do you believe this?   Can you show us some uses from published work?

Comment: Alternatively, what is the reference of "the population the feature launched to" if this is not why  "Kathmandu" is present?

Answer (score -1):

Although *Kathmandu* is a real place, the name has become a figure of speech in English meaning a distant, and perhaps little-known, place.

The inference is that a Western data analyst would be unlikely to know about the occurrence of a public holiday in a faraway place, so it represents an unexpected outlier in the data.

I work in Business Intelligence alongside data scientists who agree with me on this.

Comment: Can you provide *any published use example whatsoever* of this "figure of speech"?

Comment: Alternatively, what is the reference of "the population the feature launched to" if this is not why  "Kathmandu" is present?